# conditional add code for iOS depending on the device iOS

Tags: ios, ios9

I want to use the following code but only for devices that run in iOS < 9. In particular I want to run it on a device with iOS8.

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if(..)
      test()

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;

}

#endif
```

However when I am building the code and run it on the device the method is not executed. What I have done wrong? The app has minimum iOS supported 7.0 and can ran in iOS9 also (latest xcode 7)

Comment: You can't use preprocessor macros like this since that is a compile time feature. You need a runtime check.

Comment: Why don't you want this delegate method called for iOS 9.0 and later?

Comment: Maddy is right - preprocessor checks are not done at runtime. So you're version will either have the feature or not.  You need a runtime check like trojanfoe's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this  "System Versioning Preprocessor Macros" for checking the system version

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

Comment: What should I use in place of v for iOS9? 9000?

Comment: @cateof if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"9.0"))  like this you can use

Comment: This is not correct answer. I asked if I can do it with preprocessor macros. I don't want a method to get triggered at all if my device runs on iOS9.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000` and `#endif` and then I think this will do it:

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (version < 9.0f)
    test()
```

Comment: What is the problem with the #if #else preprocessor macros?

Comment: I think you want the same code run in every version?

Comment: No I don't want supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow to get triggered in iOS9